# How to align Navigation image in center when screen size reduces

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a navigation bar like following

```html
<!-- #region Navigation -->
<div class="container ">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top bg-white box-shadow " style="border-bottom: 4px solid #2878b7;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="@_appSettings.Value.CandidateUrl">
            <customerImage></customerImage>
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- #endregion -->
```

The image I have when I have full screen:
[image: the image I have when I have full screen.]

I need image like following with reduced screen size, which I am not getting:

[image: Reduced screen size image]

Let me know how I can align it in center with reduced screen size, please.

Comment: Are you added media query if yes try with `align-item:center` or `text-align` or with `margin-left` or `padding-left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Flexbox can do some pretty awesome things when you mix flex alignments
> with auto margins
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins

`navbar` display is `flex` and `navbar-brand` is flex item (In your markup).

One solution is to use `margin-left: auto` `margin-right: auto;`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Add  `mr-auto` class ([spacing docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)) to `navbar-brand`. And by custom code `margin-left: auto` only under some **width** (Boostrap is "mobile-first" all breakpoints use `min-width` not `max-width`).

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a style="background: red;" class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Logo</a>
</nav>
```

For testing, `expand snippet` & change the width of the window.

[image]